# Gathering Resources to Learn Statistics from the Ground Up

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I am a math grad student who recently decided to do a research study in statistics in Winter 2023. I took AP Stats in high school over ten years ago. I have a solid background in pure math and have always loved deriving everything from the ground up and I want to do the same thing with statistics.

I am currently taking a course in linear regression and statistical data analysis. I can provide course summaries in an edit/comments if it's helpful, but it's worth noting that we're using R for pretty much everything.

I am looking for solid resources for someone in my position (textbooks, papers...etc). I want a deeper understanding of statistics that factors in theory and solid examples, while starting from the ground up. I am unfamiliar with solid statistics literature the way that I am already with mathematics, so any resources that people are willing to provide are appreciated. The more conceptual the resource is, the better.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. There are plethora of posts related to resources recommendations [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mathematical+statistics+recommendations). Also, it would be better if you could narrow down your requirements as in perhaps some specialization, which also can be used to pinpoint many posts here for your help.

Comment: Many more such threads can be found bearing the [tag:references] tag.